# Apache Mahout Naive Bayes Classifier without Hadoop

Tags: apache, hadoop, machine-learning, mahout, bayesian

It is possible to use Naive Bayes Classification engine in Apache Mahout without Hadoop?
*StandardNaiveBayesClassifier* uses *NaiveBayesModel* that is actually constructed from Hadoop  related classes.
Can i run any other classifier in Apache Mahout without the need to install Hadoop on deployments server?